# where in latex.ltx is Font TU/lmr/m/n/12=[lmroman12-regular]:mapping=tex-text; at 12.0pt required

Tags: fonts, xetex, pdftex

I switched from `pdflatex` to `xelatex` to run the last draft of a project, using proper unicode fonts, and I found this error in my log

```
\share\texmf-local\tex\latex\base\size12.clo(54): Error: Font TU/lmr/m/n/12=[lmroman12-regular]:mapping=tex-text; at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.
```

Which is weird. When did I ask for lmroman here?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}

\begin{document}
Hello, Weirdo!
\end{document}
```

Comment: lmroman is the default font if you use xelatex.

Comment: the question persists: where is that defined?

Comment: in the default fd file.  `tulmr.fd`, and the family in `fonttext.ltx`.

Comment: as I wrote: in fonttext.ltx, so in the format.  lmr is set as the default family before you even load the class. Why are the fonts not installed in your system?

Comment: in a similar way pdftex will fail if computer modern is not available. Each encoding needs at least one known fallback font to exist.

Comment: i see: there is indeed a call to `fonttext.ltx` in latex; and as before, i may override it with a local `fonttext.cfg`

Comment: and the fonts are not in my system because i have no use for lmr.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Looks like an answer to me

Comment: On Manjaro, I had to install the texlive-fontsrecommended package.